# Changing margins in .sty

Tags: page-breaking, margins, paragraphs

I'm trying to change the margins in an input .sty. I'm trying to set different margins for the first and second page. I've managed to alter the margins but the first paragraph in the second page has the wide margins of the first page as latex generates the paragraph before placing it. Is there a way to automatically set a specific paragraph box for the first page to prevent this or are there any other work arounds?

Many Thanks

```
% Load Packages 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{afterpage}



% Define Dark Blue Color, Logo, and Signature Files
\definecolor{XXXblue}{RGB}{0,0,153}
\providecommand\signature{RandomSig}
\providecommand\XXXlogo{RandomLogo}


% Define Letterhead Content
\providecommand\dept{A Really Great Place}
\providecommand\deptaddress{A Subdivision of this Place \\
                        The first address line \\
                        The second address line \\
                        The third address line }
\providecommand\deptphone{123-456-7890 \\ Fax: 123-456-7890}
\providecommand\college{A Really Great Place}
\providecommand\eeo{Doing Very Interesting Things}
\providecommand\myname{Random Person \\
                   Director of Randomness \\
                   Email: \href{email@emailservice.com}      {email@emailservice.com}}
\providecommand\date{\today}
\providecommand\toName{Dear \toName}
\providecommand\toAddress{}
\providecommand\closing{Very Sincerely,}


% Header and Footer
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[L]{%
\begin{textblock*}{2in}[2in,1in](1in, 1.5in)
    \includegraphics[width=2in]{\XXXlogo}
\end{textblock*}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \draw[color=XXXblue,line width=0.7pt] (current page.north west)+ (1.18in,-1.0in) -- ($(-0.625in,-1.00in)+(current     page.north                east)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{textblock*}{2in}(3.36in, 2.18in)
    \scriptsize\color{XXXblue} \textbf{\dept}
\end{textblock*}
\begin{textblock*}{2in}(5.33in, 2.18in)
    \scriptsize\color{XXXblue} \deptaddress
\end{textblock*}
\begin{textblock*}{1in}(7.30in, 2.18in)
    \scriptsize\color{XXXblue} \deptphone
\end{textblock*}
}
\fancyfoot[L]{%
\begin{textblock*}{1.5in}(1.58in,10.40in)
    \scriptsize\color{XXXblue} \college
\end{textblock*}
\begin{textblock*}{2in}(6.60in,10.40in)
    \tiny\color{XXXblue} \eeo
\end{textblock*}    
}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\setlength{\topmargin}{1in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{1in}%
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{1in}%
\setlength{\textheight}{9.0in}%
\fancyhead{}%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
}


% Insert line between paragraphs and don't indent first line
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.8\baselineskip}
\pagestyle{empty}





\interlinepenalty 10000
\setlength{\topmargin}{1.5in}%
\setlength{\textheight}{6.0in}%
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{1in}%
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{1in}%

\AtBeginDocument{%
\date \\ \\
\ifx\toName\@empty \else \toName\\ \fi
\ifx\toAddress\@empty \else \toAddress\\ \ \\ \fi
\toName \\ \newline
}




      \afterpage{%
      \setlength{\global\topmargin}{1in}%
      \setlength{\global\oddsidemargin}{1in}%
      \setlength{\global\evensidemargin}{1in}%
      \setlength{\global\hsize}{6.5in}%
      }%    





\AtEndDocument{%
\newline \newline
\closing \\ \\
\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{\signature} \\
\myname
}
```

And tex file

```
\documentclass{article}

\input{newStyle.sty}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\def\date{\today}
\def\toName{Some Really Important People} 
\def\toAddress{Their Address \\ A place, Somewhere 55555}



\begin{document} 

\lipsum[0-9]

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Your `.sty` file is a mess, unfortunately

Comment: @ChristianHupfer To the point of not obviously being a `.sty` file at all....

Comment: @cfr: Stickler to the point/rules, right? ;-)

Comment: There really are an awful lot of things wrong here. You can't/shouldn't change the page dimensions directly if using `geometry`, and you can't/shouldn't change them as part of a page style, however fancy. Definitely don't add space using things like `\newline \newline` or ``\\ \\``. Even if it appears to do what you want, it will cause untold headaches sooner or later (usually sooner).

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Like the laws of thermodynamics, yes. :)

Comment: @OP Don't mind us ;).

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your interest. I've cleaned up the code a little and added the .tex file I was using to debug it @cfr are you referring to my use of \afterpage ? Would it be better to use \atnextshipout or something like that instead?

Comment: I was referring to the things I referred to i.e. `geometry` vs. manual setting of dimensions, what should be in a page style, how to add vertical space etc. etc.

Comment: That is not very minimal, is it? As minimal examples to, that is. It shouldn't be a `.sty`. Use `.tex` and then it will at least be less confusing. In any case, your code won't compile: `RandomLogo` not found; `no line here to end`. Also, a warning: `Package textpos Warning: environment textblock* not in vertical mode. 
(textpos)                Environment textblock* should not have any text
(textpos)                or printable material appearing before it.
(textpos)                Alignment may work out wrongly. on input line 118.`

Comment: Why not use a class designed for letters if you are typesetting a letter? I tried to have a look but, frankly, I can't figure it out well enough to understand what you are trying to do. I suggest splitting your question up, if appropriate, and posting a minimal example or examples, with a clearer indication of what you want the code to do.

Answer (score 1):

This is a somewhat cleaner version of your code. At least it compiles without error. It uses `changepage` to adjust the margins on the first page. However, you must manage the page break and restore the margins in the body of your letter. At least, I cannot find a way to avoid that at the current time.

The top/bottom margins don't need adjusting - we can just leave vertical space on the first page to allow for the letterhead. So the issue is the left/right margins. Personally, I think it would look better not to change these anyway but to settle on a consistent text width throughout.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
% Load Packages
\usepackage{geometry}
  \geometry{textwidth=6.5in, top=1in, bottom=1in}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
\usepackage{changepage}

% Define Dark Blue Color, Logo, and Signature Files
\definecolor{XXXblue}{RGB}{0,0,153}
\newcommand\signature{RandomSig}
\newcommand\XXXlogo{example-image-a}

% Define Letterhead Content
\newcommand\dept{A Really Great Place}
\newcommand\deptaddress{A Subdivision of this Place \\
  The first address line \\
  The second address line \\
  The third address line }
\newcommand\deptphone{123-456-7890 \\ Fax: 123-456-7890}
\newcommand\college{A Really Great Place}
\newcommand\eeo{Doing Very Interesting Things}
\newcommand\myname{Random Person \\
  Director of Randomness \\
  Email: \href{email@emailservice.com}      {email@emailservice.com}}
\newcommand\toName{Dear \toName}
\newcommand\toAddress{}
\newcommand\closing{Very Sincerely,}

% Header and Footer
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhead{}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}

% Insert line between paragraphs and don't indent first line
\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.8\baselineskip}
\pagestyle{empty}
\newsavebox{\startletter}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \changetext{0pt}{-2in}{1in}{1in}{0pt}%
  \sbox{\startletter}{%
    \parbox{\linewidth}{%
      \@date\bigskip\par
      \ifx\toName\@empty\else\toName\par\fi
      \ifx\toAddress\@empty\else\toAddress\bigskip\par\fi
      \toName\medskip\par}}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    [
      remember picture, overlay, draw=XXXblue, text=XXXblue, font=\scriptsize, align=left
    ]
    \draw [line width=0.7pt] (current page.north west) +(1.18in,-1.0in) coordinate (c1) -- ($(-0.625in,-1.00in) + (current page.north east)$) coordinate (c2);
    \node (h1) [below=of c1, anchor=north west] {\includegraphics[width=2in]{\XXXlogo}};
    \node (h2) [right=10mm of h1, anchor=north west] {\deptphone};
    \node (h3) [right=10mm of h2.north east, font=\scriptsize\bfseries, anchor=north west] {\dept};
    \node (h4) [anchor=north east] at (h3.north -| c2) {\deptaddress};
    \node (c3) [above=.5in of c1 |- current page.south, anchor=south west] {\college};
    \node [font=\tiny, anchor=south east] at (c3.south -| c2) {\eeo};
    \node [below=of h1.south west, anchor=north west, text=black, font=\normalsize] {%
      \usebox{\startletter}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \vspace*{4in}\par}
\makeatother


\AtEndDocument{%
  \bigskip\par
  \closing\medskip\par
  \includegraphics[width=1.5in]{\signature}\par
  \myname}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\def\toName{Some Really Important People}
\def\toAddress{Their Address \\ A place, Somewhere 55555}

\begin{document}

  \lipsum[1-2]
  \clearpage
  \changetext{0pt}{2in}{-1in}{-1in}{0pt}%
  \lipsum[3-6]

\end{document}
```

[image: letter on letterpaper]

Comment: No this is not the solution. The problem is to have the margins automatically change after the first page from the preamble or an input .sty; not to change them manually in the text. Does anyone know if it's possible to set the first page as a large \parbox then automatically feed text in?

Comment: @nboogerz That's what I said. The main point was just to post a cleaner version of your code which avoided some of the no-nos in your original. (E.g. which avoided trying to add space using `\newline` or `\\\` and which did not try to change page margins in incompatible ways.) Mostly, I aimed to get it to (1) compile without error, and (2) actually place everything on the page rather than off it.

Comment: Hi cfr, this code is running much better, thank you.

Comment: @nboogerz You're welcome. Hopefully it will encourage somebody else to add the trickery needed for an actual answer. (That is beyond me - I can lay groundwork but manipulating TeX's parsing and output routine is well beyond my ken.)