# Optional address on letter

Tags: conditionals

I'm trying to add an optional letter address that I can add to the letter by defining as true or false. Is there any reason why the address isn't printing?

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article} 
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{everyshi}
\usepackage{atbegshi}


\def\toName{Some Really Important People}
\def\toAddress{Their Address // Some St Some Town.}

\newif\ifAddOrNot
\AddOrNottrue 

\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.8\baselineskip}
\pagestyle{empty}
\newsavebox{\startletter}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{
\ifAddOrNot
\changetext{0pt}{-2in}{1in}{1in}{0pt}%
\sbox{\startletter}{%
\parbox{\linewidth}{%
 \bigskip\par
 \@date\toName\medskip\par\toAddress}}
 \else
 \fi
 }
\thispagestyle{empty}%
\vspace*{4in}\par
\makeatother    


\begin{document}


Some text

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your conditional is *never* printing anything is because you're storing the address content in a **box** using

```
\sbox{\startletter}{%
  <stuff>
}
```

but *never* using the **box** in the form

```
\usebox{\startletter}
```

Of course, storing the content in a box is not necessary if you're placing it using a conditional.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 

\def\toName{Some Really Important People}
\def\toAddress{Their Address // Some St Some Town.}

\newif\ifAddOrNot
\AddOrNottrue

\pagestyle{empty}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \ifAddOrNot
    \parbox{\linewidth}{%
      \bigskip\par
      \@date\toName\medskip\par\toAddress}
  \fi
}
\makeatother    

\begin{document}

Some text

\end{document}
```

I removed all the unnecessary content in the above minimal example.

Comment: Thanks very much Werner for your help. If you are free could you look over this other issue I was having with latex. I think a solution to this would be more beneficial to tex.stackexchange community. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220295/changing-margins-in-sty/220409?noredirect=1#comment518271_220409

Comment: @nboogerz: So the solution posted there doesn't suit your needs?

Comment: It is a way around the problem, but it would be good to be able to preset margin changes in the preamble? I was thinking one could set a parabox on the first page of specific dimension, but I've no idea if it's possible to feed text into a preset box?

Comment: @nboogerz You don't believe [David Carlisle](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223778/set-parbox-in-preamble#comment525546_223778) when he tells you that you have misunderstood what a `\parbox` is, and that it cannot possibly do what you want? You haven't said, either, why the `flowfram` solution isn't an option. I don't recommend it for your intended use, because I think this is intended as a style for others to use and `flowfram` might do unexpected things. But `flowfram` comes as near as anything I've seen to what you wish a `\parbox` could do.

Comment: @cfr Hi cfr, sorry for the late response. flowfram solution looks really really good, thanks for your time. That's exactly what I wanted to do.