# set parbox in preamble

Tags: paragraphs, preamble

is there any way to set a \parbox of a specific size in the preamble and then automatically pass text from the main body into it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\title{ParboxSample}
\author{Truly Rudy??}
\date{January 2015}


 \AtBeginDocument{
    \parbox[10cm]{\textwidth}{}
    }


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[0-6]

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you set the box anywhere (preamble or in the document) you can not pass text to it,  It is not at all clear what output you intend or what text you want in the box, possibly yyou just need to redefine `\maketitle` to use `\parbox` (and don't need teh `\AtBeginDocumet` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think this is really a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220295/changing-margins-in-sty. (That is, it is a duplicate in intended meaning, but not a duplicate in the sense of asking exactly the same thing.)

Comment: If you are really getting at the same thing as in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220295/changing-margins-in-sty, it would be helpful to link that question from here so that people understand the background of what you are trying to do. As it stands, I think you are going to get answers which e.g. give you a custom wrapper around `\parbox` or `minipage` or whatever, which (if I'm right) is not at all what you want. This is, however, a much more minimal example than your original ;) - but it would benefit from the explanation given in the other question. (Unless really a site duplicate?)

Comment: Hi cfr. Yes this is the original problem  tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220295/changing-margins-in-sty. So what happened there is we tried to change the margin size from one page to the next 'automatically' by changing the margin size in the preamble. So then the problem we encountered was that when we changed page the first paragraph printed in the margin size of the previous page, as latex compiles a paragraph of text before placing it. So if one can create text in a preset parbox hopefully paragraph margins can change smoothly between parbox and regular text?

Comment: @nboogerz I think you must be misunderstanding wnat a parbox is, there is no transition smooth or otherwise) between a parbox and the main page. Rather than ask about parbox perhaps you should edit your question to describe instead the intended layout which possibly does not involve a parbox at all.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think the original question might be a better candidate for editing, as attempting to change the margin size is really much closer to what is wanted than trying to use a `\parbox`. At least, I think so?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes I didn't understand fully the use of a parbox, I thought it was something that you could move text in and out of more easily, and wasn't a closed block of text. A parbox isn't useful for something like this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This uses `flowfram` to automatically switch the effective width of paragraphs after the first page. (This is a modification of [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/220409/) to [your other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/220295/).)

Note that you should not use `flowfram` without reading the manual as it performs major surgery on TeX's output routine and it is important to be aware of the implications of this.

This is not entirely automatic because the user needs to ensure that the first page break occurs between paragraphs. However, the user does not need to do any more than issue a `\clearpage` if required.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
% Load Packages
\usepackage{geometry}
  \geometry{textwidth=6.5in, top=1in, bottom=1in}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
\usepackage{calc,flowfram}

% Define Dark Blue Color, Logo, and Signature Files
\definecolor{XXXblue}{RGB}{0,0,153}
\newcommand\signature{RandomSig}
\newcommand\XXXlogo{example-image-a}

% Define Letterhead Content
\newcommand\dept{A Really Great Place}
\newcommand\deptaddress{A Subdivision of this Place \\
  The first address line \\
  The second address line \\
  The third address line }
\newcommand\deptphone{123-456-7890 \\ Fax: 123-456-7890}
\newcommand\college{A Really Great Place}
\newcommand\eeo{Doing Very Interesting Things}
\newcommand\myname{Random Person \\
  Director of Randomness \\
  Email: \href{email@emailservice.com}      {email@emailservice.com}}
\newcommand\toName{Dear \toName}
\newcommand\toAddress{}
\newcommand\closing{Very Sincerely,}

% Header and Footer
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhead{}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}

% Insert line between paragraphs and don't indent first line
\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.8\baselineskip}
\pagestyle{empty}
\newsavebox{\startletter}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \sbox{\startletter}{%
    \parbox{\linewidth}{%
      \@date\bigskip\par
      \ifx\toName\@empty\else\toName\par\fi
      \ifx\toAddress\@empty\else\toAddress\bigskip\par\fi
      \toName\medskip\par}}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    [
      remember picture, overlay, draw=XXXblue, text=XXXblue, font=\scriptsize, align=left
    ]
    \draw [line width=0.7pt] (current page.north west) +(1.18in,-1.0in) coordinate (c1) -- ($(-0.625in,-1.00in) + (current page.north east)$) coordinate (c2);
    \node (h1) [below=of c1, anchor=north west] {\includegraphics[width=2in]{\XXXlogo}};
    \node (h2) [right=10mm of h1, anchor=north west] {\deptphone};
    \node (h3) [right=10mm of h2.north east, font=\scriptsize\bfseries, anchor=north west] {\dept};
    \node (h4) [anchor=north east] at (h3.north -| c2) {\deptaddress};
    \node (c3) [above=.5in of c1 |- current page.south, anchor=south west] {\college};
    \node [font=\tiny, anchor=south east] at (c3.south -| c2) {\eeo};
    \node [below=of h1.south west, anchor=north west, text=black, font=\normalsize] {%
      \usebox{\startletter}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \thispagestyle{empty}}
\makeatother


\AtEndDocument{%
  \bigskip\par
  \closing\medskip\par
  \includegraphics[width=1.5in]{\signature}\par
  \myname}

\newflowframe[1]{4.5in}{5in}{1in}{0pt}[firstpagebox]
\newflowframe[>1]{6.5in}{9in}{0pt}{0pt}[otherpagebox]


\usepackage{lipsum}

\def\toName{Some Really Important People}
\def\toAddress{Their Address \\ A place, Somewhere 55555}

\begin{document}

  \lipsum[1-2]
  \clearpage
  \lipsum[3-6]

\end{document}
```

[image: letter with flow frames]

Answer (score 0):

You could do something along the following lines:

In the preamble:

```
\newsavebox\myparbox
\newcommand\setmyparbox[1]{\sbox\myparbox{\parbox[10cm]{\textwidth}{#1}}}
\newcommand\usemyparbox{\usebox{\myparbox}}
```

Comment: you could do that but it would be very odd, the `\textwidth` width is specified for linebreaking the content of the box, but no breakable content is available. also I think you mean `\sbox` not `\setbox` (or you are missing a `\hbox`)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, I did mean `\sbox`.  I should know better than just to wing it on this site, and always do a test run to make sure I'm thinking about it correctly.